# What does ls /nosuchdir 2> error.file mean in unix/linux?

Tags: linux, command

I understand the  **ls** part and redirection operator    **>** .But what does overall command do?

Comment: if [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) doesn't answer your question, re-phrase it to be more specific about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you use `>` it redirects `STDOUT`.

`STDOUT` is identified by `1`, so, for example, the two following command does the same:

```
ls > error.file
ls 1> error.file
```

Probably you already have seen sometimes command like this:

`command > error.file 2>&1`

It means: Redirect the default channel (STDOUT) to error.file and redirect `2` into the same place. That `2` stands for `STDERR`.

In your case you're redirecting only `STDERR`.

Comment: Thanks Zagorax for further clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

it puts any error messages sent to `stderr` into the file `error.file`

Without explicitly redirecting stderr, its output would go to the console by default.

See [All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) and [BASH Shell: How To Redirect stderr To stdout (redirect stderr to a File)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/)

Comment: hi thanks for the quick answer.What really confused me was `/nosuchdir` part.Some one in below forum said it's shell scripting concept.:P 
[link](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/52291-what-does-ls-nosuchdir-means.html)
This confused me even more.Now got it. Thanks a lot :)